# golang timezone daylight savings time doesn't work

Tags: go, timezone

I know that on 26 Oct, 2014 02:00am the clock should go backwards 1 hour, but I can't reproduce this using a simple golang program

```
const timeFormat = "2 Jan, 2006 3:04pm"

loc, err := time.LoadLocation("Europe/Moscow")
log.Print(loc, err)

testz , _ := time.ParseInLocation( timeFormat, "26 Oct, 2014 01:59am",  loc)
fmt.Println( testz , testz.UTC())
testz = testz.Add( time.Minute )
fmt.Println( testz , testz.UTC())
testz = testz.Add( time.Minute )
fmt.Println( testz , testz.UTC())
```

outputs

```
2014-10-26 01:59:00 +0300 MSK 2014-10-25 22:59:00 +0000 UTC
2014-10-26 02:00:00 +0300 MSK 2014-10-25 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
2014-10-26 02:01:00 +0300 MSK 2014-10-25 23:01:00 +0000 UTC
```

go 1.6, linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your output, it looks like this line:

```
testz , _ := time.ParseInLocation(timeFormat, "26 Oct, 2014 01:59am", loc)
```

... is actually giving you the *later* of the two occurrences of 1:59am, given that it's showing an offset of +3. In other words, you're looking at three minutes of time an hour later than you want to be - starting nearly an hour after the daylight saving transition.

You can change your code to start with an unambiguous value like this:

```
testz, _ := time.ParseInLocation(timeFormat, "26 Oct, 2014 00:59am", loc)
testz = testz.Add(time.Hour)
```

I'd expect that to then show

```
2014-10-26 01:59:00 +0400 MSK 2014-10-25 21:59:00 +0000 UTC
2014-10-26 01:00:00 +0300 MSK 2014-10-25 22:00:00 +0000 UTC
2014-10-26 01:01:00 +0300 MSK 2014-10-25 22:01:00 +0000 UTC
```

(I haven't tried this, as I don't have Go installed - but I'd expect it to work.)

Comment: Just checked, it shows 0:59, 1:00, 1:01 but in +0400 MSK timezone... And I don't get it... This time('2014-10-26 02:00:00 +0300 MSK 2014-10-25 23:00:00 +0000 UTC') and any further within this hour from the first output is not technically possible at all, as clocks were moved and this hour should be skipped

Comment: @let4be: Are you sure you included the `Add(time.Hour)` part? It sounds like it. Don't forget that the hour isn't skipped - it's *repeated*. I think you may have confused yourself about the kind of change this is.

Comment: @let4be: I'm installing Go now so I can try it for myself :)

Comment: @let4be: I've just tried it myself, and the output is exactly what I expect it to be. Make sure you've got the second line of the code I showed.

Answer (score -2):

It's not because your code has error,just for `time.UTC()` will print UTC time,that is timezone 0 time,and from your code `time.LoadLocation("Europe/Moscow")` we can know maybe you are in Moscow,which belongs to east timezone 3,so the time will be earlier than utc time by three hours,meaning that **<your time>=<utc time>+3.**

Comment: correct, but i'm talking about _daylight_ savings times, and this an is _additional_ +/-1 hours shifting in addition to the timezone. 26 Oct, 2014 02:00am was the last time we've had this time shift, golang doesn't seem to know about this... Other time shiftings regarding daylight savings time seem to work within Europe/Moscow timezone, just not this specific date/time

Comment: The OP is printing both `testz` and `testz.UTC()`. Look at the output - each line contains the local time *and* the UTC time. The OP is (understandably) alarmed that the UTC offset isn't changing when they expect it to be - which is explained in my answer.